# Make a dictionary out of all dataframes with certain suffixes and prefixes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of dataframes that I would like to group into dictionaries based on prefixes and suffixes:

```
prefixes = ['one_season_bucket',
'two_season_bucket',
'three_season_bucket',
'four_season_bucket']
```

suffixes:

```
suffixes = ['racer_bio',
'spring_rate',
'neaps_rate',
'spring_raw',
'neap_raw',
'opposing_team',
'opposing_team_distribution',
'stern_score',
'bow_score',
'team_score']
```

example of some dataframe names:

```
...
two_season_bucket_year1_racer_bio
two_season_bucket_year1_spring_rate
two_season_bucket_year1_neaps_rate
two_season_bucket_year1_spring_raw
two_season_bucket_year1_neap_raw
two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team
two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team_distribution
two_season_bucket_year1_stern_score
two_season_bucket_year1_bow_score
two_season_bucket_year1_team_score
four_season_bucket_year4_racer_bio
four_season_bucket_year4_spring_rate
...
four_season_bucket_year4_neaps_rate
four_season_bucket_year4_spring_raw
four_season_bucket_year4_neap_raw
four_season_bucket_year4_opposing_team
four_season_bucket_year4_opposing_team_distribution
four_season_bucket_year4_stern_score
four_season_bucket_year4_bow_score
four_season_bucket_year4_team_score
```

basically I want to use these lists to make dictionaries with the dataframe name as the key and the data frame as the value, broken out by prefixes, inclduing all the suffixes, such as:

```
two_season_bucket_suffixes = {'two_season_bucket_year1_racer_bio':two_season_bucket_year1_racer_bio,
'two_season_bucket_year1_spring_rate':two_season_bucket_year1_spring_rate,
'two_season_bucket_year1_neaps_rate':two_season_bucket_year1_neaps_rate,
'two_season_bucket_year1_spring_raw':two_season_bucket_year1_spring_raw,
'two_season_bucket_year1_neap_raw':two_season_bucket_year1_neap_raw,
'two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team':two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team,
'two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team_distribution':two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team_distribution,
'two_season_bucket_year1_stern_score':two_season_bucket_year1_stern_score,
'two_season_bucket_year1_bow_score':two_season_bucket_year1_bow_score,
'two_season_bucket_year1_team_score':two_season_bucket_year1_team_score,
'two_season_bucket_year2_racer_bio':two_season_bucket_year2_racer_bio,
'two_season_bucket_year2_spring_rate':two_season_bucket_year2_spring_rate,
'two_season_bucket_year2_neaps_rate':two_season_bucket_year2_neaps_rate,
'two_season_bucket_year2_spring_raw':two_season_bucket_year2_spring_raw,
'two_season_bucket_year2_neap_raw':two_season_bucket_year2_neap_raw,
'two_season_bucket_year2_opposing_team':two_season_bucket_year2_opposing_team,
'two_season_bucket_year2_opposing_team_distribution':two_season_bucket_year2_opposing_team_distribution,
'two_season_bucket_year2_stern_score':two_season_bucket_year2_stern_score,
'two_season_bucket_year2_bow_score':two_season_bucket_year2_bow_score,
'two_season_bucket_year2_team_score':two_season_bucket_year2_team_score}
```

is it possible to do this? create a dictionary using two lists?

Comment: In what structure are your dataframes and their names currently saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have prefixs, suffixs and years, you can construct your keys for your dictionary by `'%s_%s_%s' %(prefix, year, suffix)`
since your DataFrame has the same names as your constructed key, you can use `eval` on the same string to get their value and assign them to you keys.
see example below.

```py
from itertools import product
years = ['year1', 'year2']
prefix = 'two_season_bucket'
two_season_bucket_suffixes = {'%s_%s_%s' %(pre, y, suff): eval('%s_%s_%s' %(pre, y, suff)) for y, suff in product(years, suffixes)}
```

Comment: thank you, this works. occasionally one of the combinations does not work (it doesn't exit), how could I write it to skip ones that do not work and just keep making the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

List the total combination of prefixes and suffixes by combining each with `itertools.product()`. Assign the list to a dictionary format. Does this fit your question?

```
import itertools

dicts = {}
for k in dict_lst:
    dicts[v1+'_'+v2] = v1+'_'+v2
dicts
{'one_season_bucketracer_bio': 'one_season_bucketracer_bio',
 'one_season_bucketspring_rate': 'one_season_bucketspring_rate',
 'one_season_bucketneaps_rate': 'one_season_bucketneaps_rate',
 'one_season_bucketspring_raw': 'one_season_bucketspring_raw',
 'one_season_bucketneap_raw': 'one_season_bucketneap_raw',
 'one_season_bucketopposing_team': 'one_season_bucketopposing_team',
 'one_season_bucketopposing_team_distribution': 'one_season_bucketopposing_team_distribution',
 'one_season_bucketstern_score': 'one_season_bucketstern_score',
 'one_season_bucketbow_score': 'one_season_bucketbow_score',
 'one_season_bucketteam_score': 'one_season_bucketteam_score',
 'two_season_bucketracer_bio': 'two_season_bucketracer_bio',
 'two_season_bucketspring_rate': 'two_season_bucketspring_rate',
 'two_season_bucketneaps_rate': 'two_season_bucketneaps_rate',
 'two_season_bucketspring_raw': 'two_season_bucketspring_raw',
 'two_season_bucketneap_raw': 'two_season_bucketneap_raw',
 'two_season_bucketopposing_team': 'two_season_bucketopposing_team',
 'two_season_bucketopposing_team_distribution': 'two_season_bucketopposing_team_distribution',
 'two_season_bucketstern_score': 'two_season_bucketstern_score',
 'two_season_bucketbow_score': 'two_season_bucketbow_score',
 'two_season_bucketteam_score': 'two_season_bucketteam_score',
 'three_season_bucketracer_bio': 'three_season_bucketracer_bio',
 'three_season_bucketspring_rate': 'three_season_bucketspring_rate',
 'three_season_bucketneaps_rate': 'three_season_bucketneaps_rate',
 'three_season_bucketspring_raw': 'three_season_bucketspring_raw',
 'three_season_bucketneap_raw': 'three_season_bucketneap_raw',
 'three_season_bucketopposing_team': 'three_season_bucketopposing_team',
 'three_season_bucketopposing_team_distribution': 'three_season_bucketopposing_team_distribution',
 'three_season_bucketstern_score': 'three_season_bucketstern_score',
 'three_season_bucketbow_score': 'three_season_bucketbow_score',
 'three_season_bucketteam_score': 'three_season_bucketteam_score',
 'four_season_bucketracer_bio': 'four_season_bucketracer_bio',
 'four_season_bucketspring_rate': 'four_season_bucketspring_rate',
 'four_season_bucketneaps_rate': 'four_season_bucketneaps_rate',
 'four_season_bucketspring_raw': 'four_season_bucketspring_raw',
 'four_season_bucketneap_raw': 'four_season_bucketneap_raw',
 'four_season_bucketopposing_team': 'four_season_bucketopposing_team',
 'four_season_bucketopposing_team_distribution': 'four_season_bucketopposing_team_distribution',
 'four_season_bucketstern_score': 'four_season_bucketstern_score',
 'four_season_bucketbow_score': 'four_season_bucketbow_score',
 'four_season_bucketteam_score': 'four_season_bucketteam_score'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part is easy. Use a list comprehension such as

```
lst = [ pre + '_' + post for pre in prefixes for post in suffixes]
dct = dict(zip(lst, lst))
```

In case you need to create the variables you could do (e.g.)

```
for i,k in enumerate(lst):
    vars()[k] = i       # creates the vars and assigns the index as value
```

I'm not sure if you really want that.